# Variable declaration differences var with cast or

Tags: c#, compilation, runtime

Is there any background difference between two declarations:

```
var x = (string)null;
```

and

```
string x = null;
```

Will the runtime treat this declarations different ways? Will the compiler produce the same IL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it produces the same IL:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = (string)null;
    string y = null;
}
```

Produces (with optimizations turned off):

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  ldnull      
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // y
IL_0005:  ret
```

From the compilers perspective, you are assigning `null` to a `string` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the compiler does not know the type of `x` unless you specify it in the cast. The resulting IL codes are however the same in both cases.